# Including script tags inside element Vue vm is binding to throws template error

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I have the following laravel layout template:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <link href="{{ URL::asset('css/libs.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="{{ URL::asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    @yield('styles')

    @yield('scripts.header')

 </head>
 <body>

    <div id="app">

        <div class="main-container">
            <div class="ad ad-leaderboard hidden-xs">
                <script>
                       function onSubmit(token) {
                           $("#register-form").submit();
                       }
                </script>
            </div>

            @include('layouts.partials.header')

            <div id="main">
                @yield('content')
            </div>

            @include('layouts.partials.footer')

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Jquery, Bootstrap, Moment, DatetimePicker, Sweetalert, Select2 -->
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('js/libs.js')}}"></script>

    <!-- Custom -->
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>

    @yield('scripts.footer')


   </body>
</html>
```

In `<script src="{{ URL::asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>` I have the following to set up Vue:

```
const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app'
});
```

Now I have some google add scripts I want to include within my content but I get
`[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:` error in console.

I only use Vue components on a few pages so should I move the vue declaration above out of `app.js` and move to the dedicated pages or is there a better alternative to organize this so that I can keep the declaration in the main layout page without having to keep repeating it on separate pages yet still have the ability to inline javascript?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the `<script>` tag inside your `#app` div.

```html
<script>
    function onSubmit(token) {
        $("#register-form").submit();
    }
</script>
```

You should move this to the end of the document with the other JS.

**EDIT**

Alternatively, you might look at something like this to allow you to add scripts to Vue components.
https://github.com/TheDynomike/vue-script-component

Then you could create a Vue component for each ad script, which you could drop into the page where you need it.

Comment: I added that to give an example. I have other scripts that need to be embeded within the main content so that i can display ads.

Comment: I've added a link to a component which may be able to help you add scripts to your Vue app.  You may want to research what other components are available before making a decision.